# Xamarin with Visual Studio not detecting CPU/ABI system image for emulator, even though system images are installed

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Xamarin with Visual studio 2017 and I'm having a lot of trouble getting an emulator to work with API version 25.

I have the system images installed, but the Emulator Manager does not detect them for setting up an AVD.

Here's some screenshots:
[Android SDK Screenshot, all images are installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lq3CA.png)

[Android Emulator Manager Screenshot, cannot detect CPU/ABI system image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY18Q.png)

I've tried reinstalling visual studio and xamarin, reinstalling the sdks, repairing visual studio, reinstalling everything again, etc. What do?

Comment: You are using the old AVD Manager, use the [new one](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/android-emulator/xamarin-device-manager/), Android Studio, or the `avdmanager` CLI.

Comment: Doesn't the Visual Studio Android SDK Manager work fine for API version 25?

Comment: It would be best to upgrade to the latest tools as Google recently deprecated these old GUI programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jon Douglas already given the answer, I just post a more detailed answer in order to help people who has the same problem.

> Xamarin with Visual Studio not detecting CPU/ABI system image for emulator, even though system images are installed

As Jon Douglas said, it would be best to upgrade to the latest tools as **Google recently deprecated these old GUI programs**. Here are two solutions to solve your problem.

## Solution 1 :

I would recommend you try installing `Android Studio`, and **you can share the already installed Android SDK so it will not download again**.

- 1. Install [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html?hl=en-us), the Official IDE for Android.
- 2. Create a blank project and open it.
- 3. Change Android SDK Path.

     - a. Go to `File` -> `Project Structure`
     - b. Change the SDK location to your Visual Studio SDK Location

       - I. Default Xamarin Android SDK Location is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`, you could find it in VS : `Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings`
       - II. There is a problem when you change the SDK Location: [cannot contain whitespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjbDr.png). You could open `CMD` as Administrator and type: `mklink /J C:\Program-Files-(x86) "C:\Program Files (x86)"`, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWPg9.png).
       - III. Then you could change the SDK Location, [effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt81Y.png).
- 4. In Android Studio, go to: `Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager -> Create Virtual Device`, see if it works to create a virtual device with system images you have installed.

## Solution 2 :

Try using the new AVD Manager: [Xamarin Android Device Manager](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/android-emulator/xamarin-device-manager/).

- 1. [Installing the Device Manager](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/android-emulator/xamarin-device-manager/#Installing_the_Device_Manager).
- 2. [Launching the Device Manager](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/android-emulator/xamarin-device-manager/#Launching_the_Device_Manager)
- 3. Then when you use this `Xamarin Android Device Manager` to [create a new device](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/android-emulator/xamarin-device-manager/#New_Device), you should be able to find the system images you have installed.

## Update:

> What tools in particular?

#### I mean the latest version of [Xamarin Android Device Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/xamarin-device-manager?tabs=vswin).

[image]

As of `Android SDK Tools` version `26.0.1`, Google has removed support for their UI-based AVD and SDK managers in favor of their new CLI (Command Line Interface) tools.

Because of this change, you must use the [Xamarin SDK Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-sdk?tabs=vswin) and [Xamarin Android Device Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/xamarin-device-manager?tabs=vswin) when you update to Android SDK Tools `26.0.1` and later (which is required for Android 8.0 Oreo development).

Comment: You said -> As Jon Douglas said, it would be best to upgrade to the latest tools as Google recently deprecated these old GUI programs.
-> What tools in particular? -> If upgrading is the suggestion then why downloading another tool?

Comment: @AljohnYamaro, sorry for the delayed reply, I have updated my answer, please check it.