# How can i add Android Device under V4.4 to visual studio 2017 emulator Xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Hi i need to run my app on android 4.0.3 device and i downloaded them from vs sdk manager

[image: android sdk]

but when i want to create a new device 4.0.3 version , in the *Os* list is not displayed.
[image: Os list]

how can i create a device other than default device ?

Comment: Try to create it with Android Studio

Comment: @FabriBertani i must install android studio ?!

Comment: Yes, or use other emulator like [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/) or [Andy](https://www.andyroid.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I add Android Device under V4.4 to visual studio 2017 emulator Xamarin

As @FabriBertani said, you could try use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/) instead. But when I use Genymotion on my side, **I could only create the emulator that version is higher than 4.1.1**:

[image]

> i want to create a new device 4.0.3 version

So if you need to create an android 4.0.3 version simulator, I still recommended you to **use the Android Studio**,  the Official IDE for Android. It will be quite simple to create such a simulator.

When you install Android Studio, you could you could use the already installed `Android SDK`, because there's no need for you to download it again. I have written an answer about [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48289125/xamarin-with-visual-studio-not-detecting-cpu-abi-system-image-for-emulator-even/48353792#48353792) and I write it here again:

1. Install [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html?hl=en-us), the Official IDE for Android.
2. Create a blank project and open it.
3. change Android SDK Path.

   - a. Go to `File` -> `Project Structure`
   - b. Change the SDK location to your Visual Studio SDK Location

     - I. Default Xamarin Android SDK Location is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`, you could find it in VS : `Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings`
     - II. There is a problem when you change the SDK Location: [cannot contain whitespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShATk.png). You could open `CMD` as Administrator and type: `mklink /J C:\Program-Files-(x86) "C:\Program Files (x86)"`, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWPg9.png).
     - III. Then you could change the SDK Location, [effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt81Y.png).

### Effect:

In Android Studio, click `Tools` -> `AVD Manager` -> `Create Virtual Device` -> choose  a device definition -> click `Next`:

[image]