# Can Android Studio and Visual Studio safely share the same Android SDK?

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-studio, xamarin.android

I'm trying to free up some disk space and so would like one copy of the Android SDK only, aside from not wanting to maintain two of them. Currently I have one installed for each Android Studio and Visual Studio.

I noticed that there is now a separate, Xamarin specific Android SDK manager that Visual Studio uses in place of the one provided by the Android SDK itself.

Also, Visual Studio's Android NDK is located at *"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK"*. I don't recall installing it there specifically (probably used a default location), but suppose Android Studio could be pointed at it as well.

Comment: Android Studio's SDK manager can potentially break Visual Studio with an update not yet supported by Xamarin, so care must be taken. The Xamarin plugin updates the SDK when it itself is updated (the Visual Studio SDK manager doesn't detect or indicate platform updates like Android Studio's).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Can Android Studio and Visual Studio safely share the same Android SDK?

The answer is Yes, I have done this for a long time and it works fine.

[image]

In Visual Studio, Xamarin Android SDK default location is:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64
```

In Android Studio, SDK default location is:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle
```

## Use Visual Studio Android SDK only

You could refer to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48289125/xamarin-with-visual-studio-not-detecting-cpu-abi-system-image-for-emulator-even/48353792#48353792):

1. Open Android Studio, go to `File` -> `Project Structure`
2. Change the SDK location to your Visual Studio SDK Location

   - a. Change it to Xamarin Android SDK Location: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`
   - b. There is a problem when you change the SDK Location: [cannot contain whitespace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z18X5.png). You could open `CMD` as Administrator and type: `mklink /J C:\Program-Files-(x86) "C:\Program Files (x86)"`, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWPg9.png).
   - c. Then you could change the SDK Location, [effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vt81Y.png).

## Use Android Studio Android SDK only

You just need change Xamarin Android settings as the above picture. You could find it in:

```
Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Setting
```

> It is that new visual studio specific sdk manager I'm worried about.

As @Muhammad said, it won’t broke anything.

Comment: I moved java and android-sdk to *c:\bin*, but didn't test new location with xamarin sdk manager. I'm hoping it, as well as xamarin updates, don't blindly write java and android-sdk updates to *"Program Files (x86)"*, but will just move them if they do.

Comment: @sαmosΛris, if you have any problem just feel free to ask. :)

Comment: The only problem I'm seeing is that Android Studio's SDK manager isn't detecting the 8.1 platform (api 27) installed by Visual Studio recently. 8.1 wasn't even listed before I ran the 3.1.3 update, but now shows though is completely un-selected (even when showing package details).

Comment: ... oh my bad, I didn't notice the "---" in the check box after showing details, which indicates that there is an update for it (as opposed to showing a check-mark), must've took it for a collapse button ...

Comment: Visual Studio's sdk manager is not detecting/indicating an update exists for 8.1, though I think the Xamarin plugins handle them when they are updated. I think this answer's my question - **Android Studio's SDK manager can break Visual Studio with a newer update to the SDK not yet supported by Xamarin**.

Comment: @sαmosΛris, how did you update your SDK in Android Studio? Can you share a detailed specific steps so that I can reproduce this issue on my side?

Comment: Either a recent VS 2015 Xamarin update, or the install of VS 2017 (with Xamarin plugin option), updated the Android SDK (and JDK), b/c I never had 8.1 installed (or 1.8.0_172).  When Android Studio was at 3.0.3 (yesterday), I noticed 8.1 wasn't even showing in SDK Manager. However, it did show after upgrading to 3.1.3.

Comment: As far as it breaking, I haven't directly ran into this condition, but I know in the past Xamarin lagged behind Android (naturally), so for example Fragments and ViewPager weren't available in Visual Studio projects until a few months after the corresponding Android API was released.  Unless Xamarin is now getting early access to the API's, which may very well be the case at this point, such a lag could still exist (though I'm sure would be much quicker if it does).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. There is no problem at all. You can specify custom SDK path in both Android studio and Visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Yes for sure, when install visual studio 2017 you can mark in sdk global in individual components tab, and at the end its a path you referring to it in visual studio and android studio.
If you talk about manage this sdk, visual studio 2015 and older versions of visual studio 2017 uses same android sdk manager but lately there is a new sdk manager related to visual studio only not shared between android studio and visually studio

Comment: It is that new visual studio specific sdk manager I'm worried about. If it hasn't already broke anything, is it just a matter of time before it will?

Comment: @sαmosΛris it won’t broke any thing, you can try to change visual studio path to exists sdk and if there are any error it won’t effect in sdk files already downloaded